# Cannot display Users from database in localhost

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, web-applications

I'm trying to make a web app in Java that connects to a database and shows a table with users.

I have problem with this piece of code in HTML but I believe that this is only the result of earlier coding.
So the code in curly brackets ( `{{user.name}}` and other) gets underlined and says "Unresolved variable"

I have no idea where is the problem so I'm pasting my angular methods and Java code where I made a list with users that should be displayed in localhost.

This is the code from github that I tried to rewrite but instead of hotels I'm displaying Users.

https://github.com/dangeabunea/RomanianCoderExamples/blob/master/BookingDemo/src/main/resources/templates/index.html

HTML code:

```html
<!-- Display users in a table -->
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Surname</th>
         <th>Login</th>
         <th>Is Deleted?</th>
         <th style="width: 90px"></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
         <td>{{user.name}}</td>
         <td>{{user.surname}}</td>
         <td>{{user.login}}</td>
         <td>{{user.isDeleted}}</td>
         <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</button>
          </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript (angular):

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('UserController', UserController);

UserController.$inject = ['$http'];

function UsersController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.users = [];
    vm.getAll = getAll;
    vm.deleteUser = deleteUser;

    init();

    function init(){
        getAll();
    }

    function getAll(){
        var url = "/users/all";
        var usersPromise = $http.get(url);
        usersPromise.then(function(response){
            vm.users = response.data;
        });
    } 

    function deleteUser(id){
        var url = "/users/delete/" + id;
        $http.post(url).then(function(response){
            vm.users = response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Java:

```java
@Component
public class DatabaseSeeder implements CommandLineRunner {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseSeeder(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository =  userRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        List <Users> users = new ArrayList<>();

        users.add(new Users("John", "Kowalski",  "john332", false));
        users.add(new Users( "Debby", "Ryan", "debbs84", false));
        users.add(new Users( "Michael", "Smith", "grizzly98", false));

        userRepository.saveAll(users);
```

Comment: Do you get errors when running the project? or are the errors being displayed while you are editing only?

Comment: @Spiderman No, I get no errors. It compiles and I see table but it doesn't fill with the users. It is just underlined.

Comment: If you have your own app you should provide the link to your github repository.

Comment: Check the network tab in the Developer Console. Is the response from the server correct? Inspect the table with the elements pane of the Developer Console. Is the `ng-repeat` directive rendering `<tr>` elements?